# Oracle 11g temporary list object from query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to find if there is a way in Oracle 11g, that I can store the resulting list from a SELECT into a variable (object) and then loop through that list performing a second query on the results?

Basically what I am trying to do, is get a list of all tables with a column name, then removing certain data from them tables.

Something like:

```
var PRODUCTID_TABLE = SELECT table_name 
                        FROM user_tab_columns 
                       WHERE column_name = 'PRODUCT_ID' 
                         AND table_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%';

FOR T IN PRODUCTID_TABLE LOOP

    DELETE FROM T.TABLE_NAME WHERE PRODUCT_ID = {value};

END LOOP;
COMMIT;
```

Thanks in advance

KS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always generate the DELETE statements like this:

```
SELECT 'DELETE FROM ' || table_name ||
       ' WHERE PRODUCT_ID = {value}; '
  FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE column_name = 'PRODUCT_ID' AND table_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%';
```

Or, if using PL/SQL is an option, you can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE inside a PL/SQL block:

```
BEGIN
  FOR v_rec IN (SELECT table_name
                  FROM user_tab_columns
                WHERE column_name = 'PRODUCT_ID'
                  AND table_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM ' || v_rec.table_name ||
                      ' WHERE PRODUCT_ID = {value}; ';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I like option one. Is there a way to then run those generated DELETE statements immediately after, as oppose to copying them and running them manually?

Comment: Don't think it is possible unless you write a stored function that will run the query using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. You would then run it inside the first query like: `SELECT run_dynamic_delete(table_name) 
                        FROM user_tab_columns 
                       WHERE column_name = 'PRODUCT_ID' 
                         AND table_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%';`

Comment: Cheers for that, I turned it into a two step job in the end. Ran this script to build the DELETE scripts(s) then had them copied into a .sql and ran through sqlplus